# I am not able to select options using selenium webdriver in python django

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to select a dropdown option and whenever I run it, it throws an error. I am new to Selenium. So any advice would be helpful.
Here is my HTML code

```
<select name="department" required="" id="id_department">
    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
    <option value="SubAssembly">SubAssembly</option>
    <option value="BoardTest">BoardTest</option>
    <option value="PCBoards">PCBoards</option>
    <option value="TechAssembly">TechAssembly</option>
    <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
    <option value="Welding">Welding</option>
    <option value="SM">SM</option>
    <option value="Mach">Mach</option>
</select>
```

Here is my Selenium code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from accounts.models import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import pytest

class TestProjectRegisterPage(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('functional_test/chromedriver.exe')
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()
    
    def test_no_project_alert_is_displayed(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('REGISTER').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        username = self.browser.find_element("id_username")
        username.send_keys('aayush')
        email = self.browser.find_element("id_email")
        email.send_keys('aayush@gmail.com')
        department = Select(self.find_element("id_department")).select_by_visible_text('Testing')
        time.sleep(10)
```

What am I missing here?Thanks. I am using chrome web driver

Comment: Add your code before Select

Comment: @vitaliis Hey thanks, can you please clarify

Comment: Your question lack some important details. The actions you do before selecting. I'll post one answer, but I am not sure there is just this problem

Comment: @vitaliis I added all of my code for Selenium.

Comment: Ok, check the answer. It answers your initial question

Comment: You said "it throws an error" but you haven't posted the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

department = Select(self.find_element_by_id("id_department"))
department.select_by_visible_text('Testing')
```

But you use: `Select(self.find_element("id_department"))`

Also, add at least `driver.implicitly_wait(20)` in setup method. Try removing `time.sleep()` after it, one by one.

Small update:

`self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('REGISTER').click()`,

`username = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_username")`,

`email = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_email")`,

`department = Select(self.find_element_by_id("id_department"))`

It's for the case when all your locator are either IDs or link_text.

Read here about locator types https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Can you share `live_server_url`?

Comment: Do you see the difference? You forgot locator type

Comment: Try experimenting yourself, if everything works, accept the answer. As you can see Select is not the only one problem in your code.